# How many times value is copied when we return object by value?

Tags: c++

I want to know if my understanding of temporary objects and returning by value is correct. So consider next code:

```
int function()
{
    int value = 0;
    /*
    Some calculations
    */
    return value;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = function();

    return 0;       
}
```

So when we call `function` in `main` does temporary object with scope of expression is created and value of return expression which resides in stack gets copied into it? So total number of copying in expression `int i = function();` will be 2?

Comment: I assume, you may be interested in this (old) [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140113221447/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/#fnref:saks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be 0, 1 and 2, depending on compiler optimization capabilities and setting. See e.g. this answer:

[What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

One way how to be sure is to inspect the assembly created by your compiler. Another way is to use a single value class and add a print to all special member functions to see what is happening during the object lifetime.